# How to get rid of error when building React-native app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I have created an application on React-native and have fully tested it on Android platform, where it works perfectly well. Now I want to build it for iOS. 
So what I did was:

1. Cloned the repository of my project from GIT to my Mac machine
2. Run npm install
3. Run react-native link
4. Run react-native run-ios

This launched the simulator perfectly and I got exactly what I wanted.

But, when I try to build my app in Xcode, it fails with the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DataCollector-ggwfxznelyjbjzcodfrlmajkazaj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'    
ld: framework not found React
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using React-native version 0.35 on Mac OS 10.11.6 with Xcode 8.1.

Comment: did you open the correct file in xcode? If you are using pods for example you have to open xcworkspace file (or something like that)

Comment: I'm opening DataCollector.xcodeproj file in XCode

Comment: Are you using cocopods? You need to open `DataCollector.xcworkspace`.

Comment: No, I'm not using CocoaPods at all. Do I need to?

Comment: Ok, I tried it too. I installed cocoapods on my machine and opened DataCollector.xcworkspace file in XCode. After pressing Build and Run I got exactly the same error with linker not finding React.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you by any chance remember what solved your problem? Thank you

Comment: Hey @GabrielSchneider! Yes, I briefly remember what solved the problem back then. I think it has something to do with React Native version. It was 0.35 back then, and I remember it would generate you two different types of files in "ios" folder that you could open in XCode. One of them was <project>.xcodeproj, and another <projec>.xcworkspace. So, when I was trying to open .xcodeproj file and run it in XCode, I would get that error that I wrote about above. But if instead I chose .xcworkspace, it would work perfectly well.

Comment: I noticed that current version of React Native generates only .xcodeproj file in "ios" folder. And it works well now :)

Comment: @Akbar thank you for the explanation, although it didn't help me since I am openning the .xcworkspace file I appreciate the reply :)

Comment: @GabrielSchneider Have you found a solution? I am also opening .xcworkspace (since this is what pod install output tells you to do...)

Comment: @Yossi sorry for the late reply. I stoped working on this project and never went further into solving the issue I think. Although it's been so long I can't even remember. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: I don't remember :)